# How to install google earth?

Tags: installation, google-earth

I've downloaded the **googleearth_6.0.3.2197+0.6.0-1_i386.deb** package. When I try installing it, it gives the following warning:

> The package is of bad quality The installation of a package which
>   violates the quality standards isn't allowed. This could cause serious
>   problems on your computer. Please contact the person or organisation
>   who provided this package file and include the details beneath.

Details:

Lintian check results for /home/dei/googleearth_6.0.3.2197+0.6.0-1_i386.deb:

```
E: googleearth: maintainer-name-missing <root@dei-HP-EliteBook-6930p>
E: googleearth: maintainer-address-malformed <root@dei-HP-EliteBook-6930p>
```

So what should I do? Can I ignore the warning and proceed with the installation?

Answer (score 2):

This particular error can be due to a poorly created package by the author - most of the time you can ignore the error.  However this is your risk.

First double check where you have downloaded the deb.  Is it from a known trusted source?

Also - think carefully why you dont use the similarly named package from the repository.  The version in the repository is of an accepted quality and has been tested by many people.

You can install this from the command line as well - the error will not be displayed i.e.

```
sudo dkpg -i <packagename>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
sudo dpkg -i /home/dei/googleearth_6.0.3.2197+0.6.0-1_i386.deb
```

Comment: Well it's not an answer. I asked shell I install it, I didn't ask how to install it with terminal. but anyway I installed it and it seems to work good.

Answer (score 0):

"The installation of a package which violates the quality standards isn't allowed. This could cause serious problems on your computer. Please contact the person or organization who provided this package file and include the details beneath."

Sometimes, the packages are really of bad quality but most of the time, it is just a false positive. There is not much we can do to check the quality of those packages but if you trust the source, you can try these alternatives for package installation.

A "bad quality package" most probably does not affect your overall system stability or break your system. This is even less so when you trust your source. There even is a list maintained by Debian that shows occurences of Lintian tags in packages from the Debian archives.

Nevertheless it is a good idea to find out what exactly is wrong before we install such a package. This will also help you filing a bug report to give packaging people a chance to fix it.